# NSDateFormatter - 1 day incorrect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am importing a CSV file with a date format of month/day/year (e.g. 21/01/2007).

I am looping through the CSV some are working but some are coming out with the date 1 day previous with a time of 23:00? One of the dates that are not working would look like this:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10/7/2007"];
```

but when I output the date in an NSLog it has this:

```
    NSLog(@"Date: String: %@ Date: %@", @"10/7/2007", date);
```

Date: String: 10/7/2007 Date: 2007-10-06 23:00:00 GMT

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you have a timezone problem, have you set the timezone?

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy ZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10/7/2007 +000"];
 NSLog(@"Date: String: %@ Date: %@", @"10/7/2007", date);

Comment: Fixed with:
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]; Cheers!